# Angular.js Select option without using ng-option directive

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-scope, angularjs-ng-repeat

I get an json oject from a service, and I use some of it's fields to populate my select option list. 
When I try to print the selected value in my controller, output response is "undefined".

Where am I wrong?
JSON

```
[ {
   "Accreditment" : {
      "Id" : "1",
      "Creator" : "John Smith",
      "IdCreator" : "1",
      "CreationDate" : "2014-07-01T18:13:51+02:00",
      "CostCenter" : [ "5411-Channel1", "5412-Channel2" ],
      "Destination" : [ "Playout Channel1", "Playout Channel2" ],
      "IdUserEnabled" : [ "1", "2" ],
      "WorkOrderType" : [ "New Asset", "Subtitling" ],
      "StartDate" : "2013-05-04T18:13:51+02:00",
      "EndDate" : "2014-10-04T18:13:51+02:00",
      "Status" : "enabled"
   }
} ]
```

HTML

```
<select class="form-control" ng-model="myOption" ng-change="selectAction()">
 <option  ng-repeat="cost in work.Accreditment.CostCenter" value="{{cost}}">{{cost}}</option>
</select>
```

CONTROLLER

```
mwm3.controller('CreateWorkOrderCtrl',function($scope){
    $scope.selectAction=function(){
        console.log($scope.myOption);
    };
});
```

Comment: what is `work` for ng-repeat, are you getting values filled in select ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue is with your JSON.

Just remove the array of the JSON. It will work Fine.

Read more about [JSON](http://json.org/)
JSON is an object not an array!

correction:

$scope.work =  {
     "Accreditment" : {
        "Id" : "1",
        "Creator" : "John Smith",
        "IdCreator" : "1",
        "CreationDate" : "2014-07-01T18:13:51+02:00",
        "CostCenter" : [ "5411-Channel1", "5412-Channel2" ],
        "Destination" : [ "Playout Channel1", "Playout Channel2" ],
        "IdUserEnabled" : [ "1", "2" ],
        "WorkOrderType" : [ "New Asset", "Subtitling" ],
        "StartDate" : "2013-05-04T18:13:51+02:00",
        "EndDate" : "2014-10-04T18:13:51+02:00",
        "Status" : "enabled"
       }
    }

Answer (score 0):

I have added ng-selected. Try this out.

```
<select class="form-control" ng-model="myOption" ng-change="selectAction()">
  <option  ng-repeat="cost in work.Accreditment.CostCenter" value="{{cost}}" 
   ng-selected="cost==myOption">
     {{cost}}
  </option>
</select>
```

Hope this helps.....

Answer (score -1):

As I see from your tags, you're using angularjs. Angular has its own directive for the select tag. It goes something like this:

```
   <select ng-model="myCost" ng-options="cost in work.Accreditment.CostCenter">
      <option value="">-- choose cost --</option>
    </select>
```

And, yes, remove the array brackets from your json. You're traversing an object in this case. No need for an array.

Answer (score -1):

Why don't you just do it like [this](http://plnkr.co/edit/VwLR2nlM2FvdFaxRadkx)?

```
<select ng-model="selectedItem" ng-options="item as item.Accreditment.Creator for item in list"></select>
```